# How to open other screen from react-native listview item

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux, react-native-listview

I am trying to open another screen when I do `onPress` on any item of the `listview`.

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor={AppColors.black}
                            onPress={Actions.SubCategoryList(item.guid)}>
        <View>
                 <Item style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 50, borderBottomWidth: borderWidth}}>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontFamily: AppStyles.fontFamily,
                        fontSize: 17,
                        flex: 5,
                        color: AppColors.black
                    }}>{item.category_name}</Text>
                    <Item style={{flex: 1, borderBottomWidth: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                        <Text style={{
                            color: AppColors.grey,
                            fontFamily: AppStyles.fontFamily,
                            fontSize: 17,
                            marginRight: 15
                        }}>{item.active_tournaments}</Text>
                        <Image resizeMode="contain" source={require('../../assets/images/right.png')}
                               style={{width: 15, height: 15, marginTop: 3}}/>
                    </Item>
                </Item>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
```

But whenever I came on current screen it directly goes on Subcategory screen without clicking.

And I want to know how to catch data send from the current screen on another screen.

Comment: use arrow function onPress={()=>{Actions.SubCategoryList(item.guid)}}

Comment: I already tried that but when I put that nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are actually calling `onPress` immediately instead of setting it as a callback. You can see this in the following code:

```
onPress={Actions.SubCategoryList(item.guid)}
```

You have two options to fix this. Your first option is to add a function call in there like so:

```
onPress={() => Actions.SubCategoryList(item.guid)}
```

your second option is to change the `Actions.SubCategoryList` function to return a callback something like this:

```
export function SubCategoryList(guid){
  return () => { // this gets called by onPress

    /* contents of function go here */

  }
}
```

Ideally for performance, you would also keep a cache of the callbacks you have created based on the guid, and return the cached copy instead of creating a new one. This is called memoization, and would look like this:

```
let cache = {};
export function SubCategoryList(guid){
  return cache[guid] || (cache[guid] = () => { 

    /* contents of function go here */

  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried using list view on click to log, see the sample code

```
constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }    
<View>
        <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => 
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{console.log("clicked-- data-->>",rowData)}}>
      <Text>{rowData}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>}
      />
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use [StackNavigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) which allows you to navigate through screens, to pass params,ie: list item you could use sth like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
    };
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
        <Button
          title="Go to Jane's profile"
          onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' }) // Sth. you want to pass to next view/screen
           }
        />
    );
    }
}
```

and then in the desired screen you could get the item you want from the props: ex.

```
initialRoute={{
   component: MyScene,
   title: 'My Initial Scene',
   passProps: {myProp: 'foo'},
}}
```

Another good reference:
[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)
[ComdeMentor](https://www.codementor.io/blessingoraz/understanding-navigation-in-react-native-a3wlcxmzu)